# Reduce html/javascript in telerik

Tags: telerik

I was checking Telerik UI for ASP.NET AJAX Q1 2014 trial version for feasibility.
I found that it generates lots of JavaScript for single control.
for example, [click here](http://www.telerik.com/clientsfiles/1f1cca45-e20c-400f-84d6-907a484cb328_telerik.png?sfvrsn=0) to see code generated for a RadGrid with 10 row and single column. but it generated so many JSON properties. its size is more than 2 kb.

Is it possible to reduce it?
I mean most of the properties value are default. they can be prevented.

Answer (score 0):

All possible optimization techniques that you can apply to RadGrid are listed at http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/introduction-optimizing-output-page-load-time-using-radscriptmanager-radstylesheetmanager.html